# Firebase firstore auto increment number not working (React js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
import { doc, updateDoc,} from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "../api/firebase_config";
// const mydb = firebase.firestore()
import React from 'react'
const Mcheck = () => {
async function ResetCounter() {
// userRef.update({ FieldToIncrease: increment });
const dataTable = doc(db, 'mycollection', 'Number');
const increment = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1);
console.log(increment)
// await updateDoc(dataTable, data)
const res = await updateDoc(dataTable, {
sale: increment
})
}
function checkClick() {
ResetCounter()
}
return (
<div onClick={checkClick}><input type={"submit"} value='check' /></div>
)
}

export default Mcheck
```

i searched for many solutions but its all say somthing like this. so if any one can help me then it will be very good form me.

[image: here is the error log]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're mixing and matching SDK versions, or at least syntax.

Try using the [`increment` top-level function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#web-version-9_12) from the regular v9 SDK (not its `compat` library).

```
                       // 
import { doc, updateDoc, increment } from "firebase/firestore";
...
//  remove this
//const increment = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1); 
//console.log(increment)

const res = await updateDoc(dataTable, {
  sale: increment(1) //  this increment is now the function we imported from firestore
})
```